# Network Request Failed while Integrating React Native(using Expo) to Node js

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I developed a React Native app and then i devloped Node js as a backend and write all the required REST apis.

But whenever i tried to fetch data from my backend it says **Network Request Failed**

I am starting my web server using command :-

```
npm start --host 0.0.0.0
```

And then i am checking whether i'm getting data from server or not by typing **my ip address : port** in the browser of both my android phone and laptop and there i'm getting my data.

But i don't know why is my react native app unable to fetch data...

My code is :-

```
 export const fetchDishes = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(dishesLoading(true));
    console.log("baseUrl", baseUrl);

    return fetch('https://192.168.43.182:3443/dishes')
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response;
            }
            else {
                var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
                error.response = response;
                throw error;
            }
        },
        error => {
            var errmess = new Error(error.message);
            throw errmess;
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(dishes => dispatch(addDishes(dishes)))
        .catch(error => dispatch(dishesFailed(error.message)));
}

export const dishesLoading = () => ({
    type: ActionTypes.DISHES_LOADING
});

export const dishesFailed = (errmess) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.DISHES_FAILED,
    payload: errmess
});

export const addDishes = (dishes) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_DISHES,
    payload: dishes
});
```

As u can see i have put the same ip and port in the fetch() method and still getting Network Request Failed error.

**Note:- I am running app on my physical device**

**Edit - My app is successfully fetching data on http but gives error in https.**

Comment: The browser you mentioned is your device's browser where you're able to hit the API and get data?

Comment: No,  browser of my laptop

Comment: Thought so! Try opening it from your device and see if you're able to open it as the same is what App is going to do. Ensure, you're on WiFi and not 4G and it won't be 127.0.0.1 but the IP address assigned by your Wifi router (assuming you are using wifi)

Comment: You didn't share your server code, but I imagine it has no SSL, so try using `http` instead of `https`

Comment: @Rafael Travares. It contains SSL.

Comment: @helloworlsld, yeah it is showing data in the browser of Phone too!